# Могу ли я сделать защищенный метод приватным?

Tags: c++, классы

Имеется такая ситуация:

```
class Class1 {
    protected:
        virtual void setup();
};

class Class2 : public Class1 {
};
```

В первом классе метод `setup()` объявлен protected, т е его могут использовать, помимо того же класса, дочерние классы. И то, это виртуальный метод, он будет переопределен в дочернем классе. Могу ли я его во втором классе объявить private?

```
class Class2 : public Class1 {
    private:
        void setup() {
        ...
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, можете. Эта функция будет недоступна ни для кого, кроме самого `Class2` и его друзей.

А можете объявить ее `public`, и она будет доступна для вызова извне. Но только для `Class2`, воспользоваться виртуальностью через `Class1` при этом не получится.